# Object not returning instance variable value

Tags: ruby, class, variables, output, instance

For some reason, when I call the method that tells me the object's size, I get nothing. This is my code:

```
def getSize(name)

    data = Hash.new

    data[:aarakocra] = "medium"

    print "Got size"

    return data[:aarakocra]

end

class Monster

    def initialize(name, statStr, statDex, statCon, statInt, statWis, statCha)
        @name = name
        @statStr = statStr
        @statDex = statDex
        @statCon = statCon
        @statInt = statInt
        @statWis = statWis
        @statCha = statCha
    end

    @size = "medium"

    def displayStats
        return [@statStr, @statDex, @statCon, @statInt, @statWis, @statCha]
    end

    def displaySize
        return @size
    end
end

aarakocra = Monster.new("Aarakocra", 10, 14, 10, 11, 12, 11)

if aarakocra.displaySize == "medium"
    puts "Hello"
else
    puts "Not true"
end
```

I'm expecting the output to be `hello`.

If someone could explain what's happening, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What's the point in showing the method `getSize`? It's never called in your code, and if it were, it would **always** return _medium_, so it's not really useful either.

Comment: Your variable `@size` is a so-called _class instance variable_. This is a pretty unique concept in Ruby, which is explained [here](https://www.codegram.com/blog/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/). It is basically like a class variable, but it is not shared with the subclasses (i.e. each subclass has its own copy of the variable).

Answer (score 0):

@Thrayna seems like you are initializing the instance variable `@size` outside of the initialize method, try moving the variable inside it. Since it is an instance variable, it gets initialized at object creation (Calling `Moster.new`) or when calling another method; note, that instance variables are nil by default until you initialize them.

Comment: thank you the suggestion. How would I do this without having to add an additional argument when creating the object?

Comment: Well, you don't have to... according to your example the value you are assigning is "medium", so you can just do `@size = "medium'` inside the initialize method. If you are not planning to change it though, I'd use a constant... however if you are planning to change it from outside the class, you might need to set a setter or accessor.

Check this out; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm

Comment: Oh... The methods didn't need the arguments in the first place. I do need to change it regularly because some objects will be "tiny", "small", "huge", etc.